# What is forgetting an experience?

Tags: science, nirvana

During my day to day life experience, i imagine myself with wisdom. That imagination make me take a turn to some other scene where i exist as an ultimate supreme seer and i feel touch of realisation i.e, i can even touch (or hug) that scene, things, people, everything there. I enjoy that alot.
But i forget what was the most satisfactory imagination and i keep remembering that.
I want to know :

1. What is forgetting an experience ! It is science or spirituality at the basic ?
2. is it like if i can control my imagination, i can get the understanding of the state of nirvana and Nirvana is already in me ?

Comment: Imagination is what a mind think, limitless thoughts and things. When i meditate, most of the time i get lost in something, that time i do not experience anything, its like deep in sleep (no seer exist). i do not keep a alarm clock with me to close the meditation session. When i come out of the pause (which is not actually sleep) , i start experience the world but i try to stay empty (no-perception or emotion/feelings). Now a days I think that i am missing the purpose for what i have started practicing the meditation.

Comment: i can think that i am sitting in temple on floor and drinking hard drinks.

Answer (score 3):

Nirvana isn't an experience, or a state. Nirvana is just stopping. Can you see, directly, now, that everything stops? That everything is always stopping?

When you do see that directly, that is, when your mindstream turns for one moment towards the stopping that's always happening, and you get a glimpse of Nirvana, "you" won't be there. But there will be an aftershock in your body.

That aftershock may be pleasant, and feel like wisdom- it may even feel like being a "supreme seer". But it's an experience in your body, in time, and is not itself "being in Nirvana".

Nirvana is in you because your mindstream, your experience, is always stopping. It's always going over the edge of a waterfall.

All of that might not make much sense :)

Comment: Awesome answer.

Comment: frustrating answer ;)

Comment: I don't know how but i know that every question in me starts with a gut feeling of mine that the best answer is in me and i am just a bit doubtful about giving that my consent. That doubt or circumstances which keep me away from clearing it is the distance which i have to travel/pass on my own. Thanks.